# How i can add images from another file vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, components

I have images i

```
     <div class="header-title">
        <img
          v-if="icon.length"
          :src="icon"
          class="header-icon"
        >
        {{ title }}
      </div>

 props: {
    icon: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
 }
```

And I add this image to another file:

```
  <app-dropdown-card
      title="Filters"
      icon="@/assets/images/talent-pool/filter.svg"
    />
```

But I haven't any result. The picture is right there (`@/assets/images/talent-pool/filter.svg`)
The browser sees the tag `img` but no picture is visible.

Answer (score 0):

*// Assuming you are using Vue CLI and Single-File-Components:*

You must `import` the image in the component where you are using it, and `v-bind` the image source property.

In your case it's in the file containing `<app-dropdown-card ... />`:

```
<template>
  <!-- ... -->

    <app-dropdown-card
      title="Filters"
      :icon="filterImage"
    /> <!-- Note the binding: ':icon' or 'v-bind:icon' -->

  <!-- ... -->
</template>

<script>
// Note: Vue-CLI configures Webpack loaders for SVG files and other static assets: 
import filterImage from "@/assets/images/talent-pool/filter.svg";

// ...

export default {

  // ...

  data() {
    return {
      filterImage // Note that you can't access globals from template directly
    };
  }

  // ...

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<img :src="require(`${icon}`)" />
```

sometimes it wouldn't work. try to pass the name of the image instead

```
<img :src="require(`@/assets/images/talent-pool/${iconName}.svg`)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert an Image from an local source.
In TypeScript worked this for my:

Adding direkt to the Element:

```
<img src="./vmSocks-green-onWhite.jpg" />
```

Or with binding

```
<template>
    <img v-bind:src="myImage" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';

  import testImage from "./vmSocks-green-onWhite.jpg"


  @Component({
      components: {

      }
  })
  export default class App extends Vue {    

      myImage=testImage;
  }
</script>
```